# Verificar se uma tabela existe na base de dados

Tags: php, mysql, sql-table

Como verificar se determinada tabela existe na base de dados antes de a tentar utilizar?

```php
<?php
// define a tabela
$table = 'banana';

// verificar se tabela "banana" existe aqui
// $tableExists = ??

// executa consulta se existir
if ($tableExists) {
  $query = 'SELECT * FROM '.$table.' WHERE 1';
  // executa a consulta, etc...
} else {
  die ('A tabela '.$table.' não foi encontrada na base de dados!');
}
?>
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Baseado [nesta resposta do SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525784/mysql-check-if-a-table-exists-without-throwing-an-exception), a forma mais simples é:

```php
$table = 'banana';
$tableExists = $db->query("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$table'")->rowCount() > 0;
```

Alternativamente, se alguém não quer usar PDO:

```php
$table = 'banana';
$result = mysqli_query("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$table'");
$tableExists = $result && $result->num_rows > 0;
```

Comment: A pessoa que deu o *downvote* poderia explicar o motivo? Tem algum problema de performance ou algo do tipo?

Comment: não dei downvote o 'problema' do código é que as funções mysql_* já foram depreciadas. http://br1.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php  e tem pergunta aqui sobre o assunto: http://br.stackoverflow.com/questions/579/porque-nao-devemos-usar-funcoes-do-tipo-mysql

Comment: Realmente, @perdeu está certo...hoje o melhor é utilizar PDO...

Comment: @utluiz Não dei _downvote_, mas no link que facultaste, nos comentários tem a versão em **PDO**, atualiza o teu exemplo e se era dai o _downvote_, já estás safo :)

Comment: Obrigado pelo comentário pessoal, é melhor deixar o exemplo mais adequado mesmo. Eu estava mais preocupado com o conteúdo da *query* do que com a forma de utilização no PHP e deixar passar isso.

Comment: @utluiz você poderia atualizar sua resposta usando `mysqli`? Obrigado.

Answer (score 8):

Pelo `information_schema` do mysql é possivel acessar todas as tabelas de uma database:

```sql
SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'data_base'
AND table_name = 'nome_da_tabela'
```

Após a consulta, use a função/metodo do driver do banco que retona a quantia de registros do banco:

[count()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) (genericamente)

[rowCount()(PDO)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)

[mysqli_num_rows()(mysqli)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php)

```php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost dbname=test','usuario', 'senha');
$sql = 'SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = :database
AND table_name = :tabela';

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':database', 'test';
$stmt->bindValue(':tabele', 'bananas';
$stmt->execute();
$tabelas = $stmt->rowCount();

if($tabelas >= 1 ){
  echo 'tabela valida';
  //efetuar select
}else{
  echo 'tabela invalida';
  //efetuar um create table?
}
```

sobre o [information_schema](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/tables-table.html)

Answer (score 7):

Crie uma função para que você possa fazer a busca dinamicamente:

```php
public function verificaTabela($tabela)
{
    $tabelas_consulta = mysql_query('SHOW TABLES');

    while ($tabelas_linha = mysql_fetch_row($tabelas_consulta))
    {
        $tabelas[] = $tabelas_linha[0];
    }

    if (!in_array($tabela, $tabelas)) 
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}

$tabela_existe = verificaTabela('minha_tabela');
```