# Como pegar nome das colunas de uma tabela com PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

Gostaria de pegar o nome (somente o nome) de uma tabela especifica do MySQL e exibir com PHP.

Comment: Apesar da outra questão, [Como pegar o nome de todas as tabelas de uma database mysql](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/62/como-pegar-o-nome-de-todas-as-tabelas-de-uma-database-mysql), não ser especificamente de PHP, os caminhos estão nas respostas.

Comment: [Essa outra questão](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2063/verificar-se-uma-tabela-existe-na-base-de-dados/) tem o código php fazendo uma consulta no information_schema